# What is the correct way of developing an Android platform application using Android Studio (or other IDE)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I am currently working on an Android AOSP project for which I am developing a java module which will be a part of the core services (such as the Phone app, for example).

There are some frameworks I use which are not exposed by default to "regular" apps (which lay in the private `framework.jar`).

For example: There are places I directly use `android.app.IActivityManager`'s Binder API.

I *do* own the platform keys, but I not prefer compiling the whole AOSP framework each time I want to make a change.

I also prefer working with Android Studio, but will compromise on compiling the application through the terminal, if not possible.

What is the correct way of working on a project of this kind?

How do AOSP's developers develop their code without re-compiling the whole framework each time?

**Update:**

The best way I've found so far is to simply create an android studio project, get the `framework.jar` from the device (`adb pull /system/framework/framework.jar`) or from the AOSP source code, and add it as a `compileOnly` or `runtimeOnly` dependency in the `gradle.build` file of your app.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly files('libs/framework.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Then just add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` to the Android Manifest  and compile it using the platform keys.

It should be installable as is.

This post seems to sum it up pretty good:
https://kwagjj.wordpress.com/2017/10/27/building-custom-android-sdk-from-aosp-and-adding-it-to-android-studio/comment-page-1/

Is there any other way?

Comment: http://effie.io/opening-aosp-with-intellij-part-3/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap those API callings to a new manager and service. For example, you have a manager called `CustomManager`, and it will call `IActivityManager` or other private/hidden API directly. And then you can create a module for you `CustomManager`, and build `jar/aar` for it. After every changing, you can copy that generated `jar/aar` file to you `AndroidStudio` project. You can use it as a normal library. Actually, there are some examples in `AOSP` source code, such as [SystemUISharedLib](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/shared/Android.bp;l=40), wrapper of `SystemUI` internal API, used by `Launcher3`.

Comment: Thats not exactly what I meant, I don't want just to expose an API, I want to work on the AOSP framework itself using Android Studio.

Comment: You can add your system service, and it can use `AOSP` framework hidden/system API or communicate with `AMS`, `WMS` and other system services. And then you can the mentioned method above to wrap your service with a manager, and package it as a `jar/aar` library, and then you can use it to develop your app with it to implement some functions that official Android SDK doesn't support.

Comment: So it's more or less the same as what I've wrote in the question, right?

Comment: yes. You can modified all things to `AOSP` framework source code directly, and use your mentioned method to compile you app with modified framework.jar, but it is not recommended. Adding a middle layer to abstract your modification is better, from my opinion.